# What is the normalization method so that there is no negative value?

Tags: python, normalization, image-preprocessing

I am trying to normalize MR image.
There is a negative value in the MR image.
So the MR image was normalized using the Gaussian method, resulting in a negative area. 
But i don't want to get negative area.

My question:
     What is the normalization method so that there is no negative value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To set the smallest value to zero, find the smallest value and subtract that from everything, `x[i,j] = x[i,j] - min(x)` for all pixels.  Then you can, say, divide everything by the max to get it in the range 0-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information about your source code and the packages you're using, this is really more of a data science question than a python question.

To answer your question, a more than satisfactory method in most circumstances it min-max scaling. Simply normalize each coordinate of your images between 0 and 1. Whether or not that is appropriate for your circumstance depends on what you intend to do next with that data.